# Understanding how document.getElementByClassName works - Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, document

I've read the [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName)  and [this](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_getelementsbyclassname.asp), but I'm trying to figure out how `document.getELementbyClassName` works so that I can re-implement it as an exercise. Obviously, I don't wan to just imitate the source code; my version will probably be much slower and more crude. I have a few questions, but any insight provided beyond my questions is appreciated.

1. > When called on the document object, the complete document is searched, including the root node.

   How does it search the entire document? Does this use some sort of regular expression?
2. `document.getElementsByClassName('red test');` This is supposed to return all elements that have both `red` and `test` classes. But doesn't each element only have [one class](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML_element#/media/File:HTML_element_structure.svg)? Or is this to mean something like `red orange test`?
3. Is it correct that the elements are returned in an array? Something like `[element1, element2, ...]`. I'm not sure what is meant by "array-like."

Note: I'm new to JavaScript and have even less exerpeince with HTML, CSS, and jQuery.

Comment: `document.getElementsByClassName` is written in native code, how it works internally is not very interesting if you're writing a polyfill, as you'd probably have to use `getElementsByTagName` anyway, all you need to know is what it does, and it get's elements by class name

Comment: Also, elements can have multiple classes

Comment: Elements can have 0 to many classes. `<p></p>`, `<p class="a"></p>`, `<p class="a b c"></p>` are all valid.

Comment: And here's how you polyfill it -> https://gist.github.com/eikes/2299607

Comment: It doesn't need to use a regular expression, because it operates on the DOM, not the HTML source code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your questions:

1. Probably recursively. Otherwise there are plenty of different ways to traverse `n-ary` trees which is what the DOM is. Depth-first, breadth-first, however-you-want-first-really, they can all be implemented recursively, or alternatively use some data structure like a stack or a queue. How it does it really isn't important, what matters is how YOU think it should be done.

A simple algorithm for recursively identifying elements with those classes would be something like this

```
getByClassName(class, root) {
  ret = []
  if (root has class) {
     ret.push(root);
  }
  for (each child of root) {
    append getByClassName(class, child) to ret;
  }
  return ret;
}
```

2. Elements can have multiple classes. `<a class="foo bar baz">` has classes `foo`,`bar`, and `baz`

Comment: At what point does it call itself? In other words, what would have to be met execute the recursive call?

Answer (score 1):

1. All the Javascript methods like this operate on the DOM, not the HTML source code. When the HTML is loaded, the browser parses the HTML into the DOM, which is a data structure containing objects that represent the document contents. So it doesn't need to do pattern matching, it simply searches through the data structure for elements whose class list contains the specified class.
2. ELements can have more than one class, and this is very common. For instance, you might have a `button` class for all buttons, and an `active` class for active elements. The active button might then be `<span class="button active">contents</span>`.
3. The elements are returned in an [`HTMLCollection`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection). This is an array-like object, so you can use `elements.length` to get the number of elements, and `elements[i]` to access a specific element in the collection. It's also a "live" collection, which means that if you change the DOM, the collection will automatically be updated to reflect the changes (e.g. if you remove the class from the object, it will no longer be in the collection).